# DO i need anything else like roles to install kerberoes

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos

I want to test or install Kerberoes for authentication.

Is it a part of AD DS or  a stand alone application which i can install on window server 2008

Do i need anything else to make it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special besides install AD to get kerberos. Essentially:

Kerberos + LDAP + MS Extentions to LDAP = MS AD

Basically what you have there is the following:

Kerberos does the AUTHENTICATION in an active directory network
LDAP is the AUTHORIZATION system
And then the fun little extra bit - MS Extensions to LDAP is essentially glue microsoft put in to make their applications work better (or lock you in/make your life painful when trying to integrate with other non-microsoft systems ... depends on your view)